# (pandas) How to ignoring process if dataframe empty?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

df:

```
     No     ITEM      Location   Class     Data
     14    Tiger__    Area        01 ***************************************PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP**********************************************************************************PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
     14    Tiger__    Area        02 **************************PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP*********************************************************************************PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
     14    Rabbit__   Area        01 **************************PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP*********************************************************************************PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
     14    Rabbit__   Area        02 **************************PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP*********************************************************************************PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
```

There are Dataframe. And i try to this code:

```
Tigeritem = df[df['ITEM'].str.contains('Tiger_') == True]
snakeitem = df[df['ITEM'].str.contains('Snake_') == True]
Rabbititem = df[df['ITEM'].str.contains('Rabbit_') == True]

realtiger = Tigeritem['Data'].astype(str).str.extractall('(\*+)')[0].str.len().loc[lambda x: x > 40].groupby(level=0).agg(list).str[1]
realsnake = snakeitem['Data'].astype(str).str.extractall('(\*+)')[0].str.len().loc[lambda x: x > 40].groupby(level=0).agg(list).str[1]
realrabbit = Rabbititem['Data'].astype(str).str.extractall('(\*+)')[0].str.len().loc[lambda x: x > 40].groupby(level=0).agg(list).str[1]
```

Yeah, actually in my df, there are no row which have "snake".
And when i try to my code, there is errors.   **AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!** at realsnake. cuz realsnake is emptydataframe.

and my question is

1: How to skip realsnake process? ignoring errors.

```
<expected results>

print(realtiger)
print(realrabbit)

>>> 82
    81
    81
    81
```

Comment: What result do you want to get?

Comment: Probably simplest to wrap in an `if not snakeitem['Data'].empty:` block

Comment: Are you looking for all the substrings with length > 40, or just the largest or last? Incidentally, when I run this, `realtiger` and `realrabbit` end up having `NaNs`. Did you truncate the `df` sample? Regardless, seems much easier first to do the substring extraction and group *afterwards* (and only here worry about handling a missing group). If you could please update the Q with the answer to @Nick's Q. As a start: `(\*+)` --> `(\*{41,})` and you can then skip the `.loc` part.

Comment: @Nick yeah, i did your answer but, there are lots of case that empty.. so that solution is not suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to protect your statements from performing operations on values that don't exist, there is no easy way around this.

It seems you want to keep your code as short as possible so the best you can do is use the shorthand `if` syntax:
`result = true_value if condition else false_value`

So in your example you can try something like:

```
realsnake = snakeitem['Data'].astype(str).str.extractall('(\*+)')[0].str.len().loc[lambda x: x > 40].groupby(level=0).agg(list).str[1] if not snakeitem['Data'].empty else snakeitem
```

Comment: @888Seeme this is exactly the same as using an `if` block, which you said was not suitable...

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your data frames and check if they are empty before applying the operation. This also has the upside of you not needing to copy paste code.

I would suggest creating a dictionary, in which the value of each key is one of your data frames. **Careful:** In the loop you have to reassign the data frame to the respective key in your dictionary in order for it to be 'saved'.

This could look something like:

```
df_dict = {'Tigeritem': Tigeritem, 'snakeitem': snakeitem, 'Rabbititem': Rabbititem}

for df_name in df_dict:
 df = df_dict[df_name]
 if not df.empty:
   < do something >
 df_dict[df_name] = df
```